# How to get only the messagebody of email in gridview?

Tags: vb.net, email, gridview, datagrid

```
    Dim curpath As String = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
    Dim mailbox As String = [String].Format("{0}\inbox", curpath)

    ' If the folder is not existed, create it.
    If Not Directory.Exists(mailbox) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(mailbox)
    End If

    ' Gmail IMAP server is "imap.gmail.com"
    Dim oServer As New MailServer("imap.gmail.com", _
        "snshanjava@gmail.com", "pvohhnsducvzfclx", ServerProtocol.Imap4)
    Dim oClient As New MailClient("TryIt")

    ' Enable SSL connection
    oServer.SSLConnection = True

    ' Set IMAP4 SSL port

    oServer.Port = 993

    Try
        oClient.Connect(oServer)
        Dim infos As MailInfo() = oClient.GetMailInfos()
        For i As Integer = 0 To infos.Length - 1
            Dim info As MailInfo = infos(i)
            Console.WriteLine("Index: {0}; Size: {1}; UIDL: {2}", _
                    info.Index, info.Size, info.UIDL)

            ' Receive email from Gmail server

            Dim oMail As Mail = oClient.GetMail(info)


            Console.WriteLine("From: {0}", oMail.From.ToString())
            Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}" & vbCr & vbLf, oMail.Subject)
            Dim imapMessageCollection

            ' Generate an email file name based on date time.
            Dim d As System.DateTime = System.DateTime.Now
            Dim cur As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")
            Dim sdate As String = d.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss", cur)
            Dim fileName As String = [String].Format("{0}\{1}{2}{3}.eml", _
                 mailbox, sdate, d.Millisecond.ToString("d3"), i)

            ' Save email to local disk
            oMail.SaveAs(fileName, True)
            ' Mark email as deleted in Gmail Account
            oClient.Delete(info)
        Next

        ' Quit and pure emails marked as deleted from Gmail IMAP4 server.
        oClient.Quit()
    Catch ep As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ep.Message)
    End Try
```

In above code i download mail from gmail server save those mail  into local folder "Inbox" .mail are downloaded perfectly but from this i want get only message body of those mails and display in grid view of my application .i have no idea about this. what i have to do in this above code

somebody help on this issue thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you perhaps using EAGetMail .dll?

Comment: Ya correct im using. from this above code i receive mail from gmail server but i want capture mail Fromaddress and subject and Body of mail to shown values in datagridview . can tell how to get those values of mail in gridview.


somebody help on  this issue thanks in advance.